# Git Submodule foreach alias to commit work

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have an alias set up for to commit all modified files in a packages submodules with a commit message. This used to work but lately it has stopped working guessing due to a git update.

The alias looks like this

```
    SubmoduleCommit = "!f() { git submodule foreach  'git commit --all --message=$1 || :'; }; f"
```

But it is no longer working, any ideas what would have changed. The error is that message requires a value so will not preform the git action.
If i copy the code into bash and replace the $1 with "Commit message" then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that inside the double quotes variables are immediately expanded. In your case `$1` is expanded to nothing because it was never assigned. Instead, withing single quotes, there is no expansion and the string is copied as you see it (except when you escape with `\`).

```
git config alias.SubmoduleCommit '!f() { git submodule foreach  "git commit --all --message=$1 || :"; }; f'
```

You can see how your aliases look like with

```
git config --list | grep "^alias\."
```

Comment: had to make a couple of adjustment for it to work by adding some escape characters as was getting errors around unclosed quotes but this worked `"!f() { git submodule foreach  \"git commit --all --message=$1 || :\"; }; f"`